# Failed to insert records into table in different server using sql server agent

Tags: sql-server, insert

My idea is to insert records from a table into another one in different server using T-SQL.

I've made maintenance plan along with its job and found below error.

> Executed as user: NT SERVICE\SQLSERVERAGENT. Login failed for user
>   'MANYAR\MIT-DB2$'. [SQLSTATE 28000] (Error 18456)Unable to open Step
>   output file.  The step failed.

I suspect SQLSERVERAGENT from source server might not have permission in destination server.  I've tried to execute the T-SQL script in query and the scripts work well.

Comment: Are you using a linked server or one of the functions like OPENDATASOURCE? The second server will definitely need the service account SQL Agent is using added in as a login -  hopefully this is an AD account?

Comment: Are you using a linked server or one of the functions like OPENDATASOURCE? (Yes, I used linked server). The second server will definitely need the service account SQL Agent is using added in as a login (There's already sql agent built in login and I've changed from sql agent to my own login since it has administrator role in both AD and 2 linked-sql server

Answer (score 0):

**I believe you are seeing two different errors on your history report.**

1. You should validate the step output file on the job step(s).
2. You should validate the linked server permissions & authentication.

---

### Recreating the step output error

**Testing with a location that does not exist**

Create a jobstep that tries to access a step output folder location that does not exist

*Regular T-SQL job steps might report the error but not fail the job, I used a maintenance plan to force the failure here*

[image]

Start the job

[image]

Resulting error:

> Executed as user: AgentServiceAccount. Unable to open Step
>   output file.  The step failed.

**Testing with insufficient permissions**

[image]

The same error is returned when no permissions are granted

> Executed as user: AgentServiceAccount. Unable to open Step
>   output file.  The step failed.

---

### Recreating the linked server permission error in combination with the step output error

Create a linked server

[image]

Authenticate with a non existing login

[image]

Create a job and jobstep to select from the newly created linked server

[image]

Point to a non existing output file

[image]

**With the final resulting error on job execution matching yours**

> Executed as user: AgentServiceAccount Login failed for user
>   'nonexistinglogin'. [SQLSTATE 28000] (Error 18456)Unable to open Step
>   output file.  The step failed.

Validate the job step output & the linked server permissions and authentication and you should be good to go.

Comment: thanks Randi, unfortunately it still doesn't work. The problem occurs when insert command executed by batch job sql server agent, but it works well if the command executed using query window.

Comment: When you execute using command window, it uses your account whereas in case of batch job(sql server agent), it uses service account which is used to start sql server agent service. Please use domain account to start the service and grant this domain account access to the server where is your target and it is supposed to work.